# Location of Sheba

Tags: geography, history

Where is the Biblical Sheba (famous for its queen) located today?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Melachim I 10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15894) seems to parallel the account of [Josephus' Antiquities 6:5](http://www.biblestudytools.com/history/flavius-josephus/antiquities-jews/book-8/chapter-6.html) making Sh'va the general area of Egypt and Ethiopia of that time.  (Source pulled from wiki.)